# Command + Backtick broken on macOS Sierra 10.12.3 and 10.12.4

Tags: keyboard, macos

In OS X 10.10, Cmd+` worked flawlessly. Now it's intermittent at best. I haven't changed my workflow or anything--but now the shortcut fails.  If I go into keyboard settings and change the shortcut mapping, it works again for a little bit, but then fails and I have to go change the shortcut again to make it work.

Anyone have any ideas how to diagnose (or fix!) this issue?

Comment: What shortcut is Cmd-`?  Is it something custom or specific to an app?  Missing some key details in the is question.

Comment: CMD+` cycles between all open windows in the active app. It has always worked flawlessly for me. I would try downloading the combo updater for 10.12.3 & installing to see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Update didn't fix it, unfortunately.. it's still intermittently weird.  Now on 10.12.4 (16E195)

Comment: 10.13.1 here, no issues for me, didn't have any on Sierra. Sounds dumb, but have you verified it's not just your keyboard being intermittent?

Comment: Yeah it's not my keyboard, tried plugging in different ones, same behavior.  Nice idea though.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen an issue like this recently; in Photoshop, Command-Backtick seemed to work only intermittently.

Today, I discovered that when I have my keyboard language set to Maori (to add diacritical marks to names in my SF novel), hitting Command-Backtick apparently does not send the same ASCII code as the US English keyboard.

Try checking your keyboard language in System Settings > Keyboard > Input Sources. Setting it back to US English instantly fixed it for me.